# Groupby and cumcount for valid rows only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
    ids    valid        date
0    1     False  2012-06-10
1    1     True   2012-07-11
2    1     True   2012-09-20
3    2     False  2012-01-12
4    2     True   2012-07-11
5    3     True   2012-03-09
6    3     True   2012-07-11
7    3     False  2012-12-09
8    4     False  2012-07-11
```

I want to count how many valid case the person has so far and going through them in ascending date order

```
ids              valid           date         occur
 1               False        2012-06-10         0
 1               True         2012-07-11         1
 1               True         2012-09-20         2
 2               False        2012-01-12         0
 2               True         2012-07-11         1
 3               True         2012-03-09         1
 3               True         2012-07-11         2
 3               False        2012-12-09         0
 4               False        2012-07-11         0
```

What I have tried so far:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'date'])
df['occur'] = df.groupby('valid').cumcount()+1
```

Comment: "valid" in the input is integer but is boolean in the output? How does that work?

Comment: @coldspeed I multiply the column by one to translate from true false

Comment: That doesn't explain how 1 * 1= False in row #2.

Comment: Made an edit to correct mistakes

Comment: My question is how is it possible for any False values to be present if all of the rows are > 0?

Comment: I am counting how many `valid` case each id has so far

Comment: Thanks for accepting. If the answer was helpful, you can upvote as well. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `cumcount`:

```
df['occur'] = (df.groupby(['ids', 'valid'])
                 .cumcount()
                 .add(1)
                 .where(df.valid, 0))
print(df)
   ids  valid        date  occur
0    1  False  2012-06-10      0
1    1   True  2012-07-11      1
2    1   True  2012-09-20      2
3    2  False  2012-01-12      0
4    2   True  2012-07-11      1
5    3   True  2012-03-09      1
6    3   True  2012-07-11      2
7    3  False  2012-12-09      0
8    4  False  2012-07-11      0
```